# Which of grammatical structures can indicate "your day and mood ruined"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, structure

> FOBO, or Fear of a Better Option, is the anxiety that something
> better will come along, which makes it undesirable to commit to
> existing choices when making a decision. It’s an affliction of
> abundance that drives you to keep all of your options open and to
> avoid risks. Rather than assessing your options, choosing one, and
> moving on with your day, you delay the inevitable. It’s not unlike
> hitting the snooze button on your alarm clock only to pull the covers
> over your head and fall back asleep. As you probably found out the
> hard way, if you hit snooze enough times, you’ll end up being late and
> racing for the office, **your day and mood ruined.** While pressing snooze
> feels so good at the moment, it ultimately demands a price.

I guess two cases. (they are all a kind of participial phrase)

A case : (with) your day and mood ruined.

B case : (and) your day and mood (will be) ruined.

Which of grammatical structures can indicate "your day and mood ruined"?
or else?

Answer (score 1):

It's A. It's not unusual to use a phrase to describe the subject of the sentence.

> John appeared at the window, his hair uncombed and a startled expression on his face.